# Excel VBA format a series of months with commas and a "and" at the end

Tags: vba, excel

so I have a several non-sequential rows in excel that have a certain month (I.e. C3 = "January", F3 = "October" and H3 = "December). I haven't been able to figure out how to move all of these strings into one cell with VBA and convert them into the following string

"January, October, and December"

Adding a comma between all of them has been doable but converting that final , to an "and" has been the issue.

The amount of months that are populated in cells b3:m3 are populated randomly depending on a different formula and range from 1 to 4 different months depending on the value of another row.

Any is help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for something more complicated than: `=CONCATENATE(C3,", ",F3,", and ",H3)` or `=C3&", "&F3&", and "&H3`

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't more clear. The amount of months range from 1 to 4 months that need to be ordered, and the cell/month location change depending on what the value of another cell is (The month names are in one row containing all 12 months so like B3:M3, my vba code before this prints out the month name if/when a certain criteria is met).

Comment: So if only one month is drawn I'd just need an output of "January" but if the previous B3:M3 row has four values it would need to be something like "January, February, September and December"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with data like this:

[image]

Run this code:

```
Sub months()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Set rng = wks.Range("B3:M3")

    Dim count As Integer
    count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng)
    If count < 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim result As String

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            result = result & cell.Value

            Select Case UBound(Split(result, ","))
                Case count - 2
                    result = result & ", and "
                Case count - 1
                Case Else
                    result = result & ", "
            End Select
        End If
    Next cell

    MsgBox result
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

---

Note: You can still salvage your question (keep it from getting closed) by editing the original post and including your other requirements that you listed in the comments.  Also, any screen shots etc to help define all of your requirements should be added as well.

Comment: Would also like to point out that this was doable by shifting all non empty cells (or that were populated by a month) left, counting the amount of months that had values, and making an if statement based off that that would concatenate the results, and finally clearing the used range